# Nodejs inspect port 127.0.0.1:9229 timing out

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, debugger

- Node.js Version: 12.2.0
- OS: Windows 10
- Using: VSC

I'm trying to use the debugger through chrome and it keeps giving me this error

```
$ node inspect app.js
Timeout (2000) waiting for 127.0.0.1:9229 to be free
```

No other terminals are open and I used `netstat` in the command terminal to see if the port is being used and it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

you might have to configurate your chrome.

Open.
chrome://inspect

in the Devices tab, click Configure, and them you will see the target Discovery settings.

Add, 127.0.0.1:9229 or all another ports you might have, in my case I added 127.0.0.1:9222 as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I found a git issue on node-inspect that gives a solution that worked for me. Apparently the problem is the timeout on opening the ports. The solution is to increase the timeout in the executable.

https://github.com/nodejs/node-inspect/issues/48#issuecomment-520246415

The instructions are basically opening the node.exe in a hex editor, find the portIsFree string and change the timeout from 2000 to something larger.